# Entity Framework Relationship Definition Issue

Tags: entity-framework

In my application I have Sections, Tables, Rounds and Players.

- Each Section has N Tables (Table "Keys": SectionId, TableId).
- And each Table has N Rounds (Round "Keys": SectionId, TableId, RoundNumber)

Players start at a Table but move to other Tables each Round, and are identified by the Table they started at.

In a perfect universe, I'd be able to put a Collection of Players on the Round object, and query for the right ones inside my controller. I get the round and then I'd do something like this:

```
db.Entry(theRound)  
.Collection(p => p.Players)
.Query()
.Where(p=> (p.SectionId == theRound.SectionId) &&
           ((p.TableNumber == theRound.NSPair && (p.Direction == "N" || p.Direction == "S")) ||
           (p.TableNumber == theRound.EWPair && (p.Direction == "E" || p.Direction == "W"))))
.Load();
```

Problem is, once I declare the Collection of Player Objects in Round, Entity Framework puts "Round_XXXX" fields for each of the three Round keys above into the table for Players, including it in the where clauses of that query. And it won't find them because they aren't associated with Rounds...not in that sense, anyway.

Associating a Round object with the Table Objects that the Players start at (in addition to it's "normal one) seems to be an awful kludge.

What I've done for now is annotated the Players collection to be `[NotMapped]` and executed the query from the root level context.

There is a better way to do this, right?

Comment: Sounds like a modeling problem more than an EF problem, per se.  For instance Player wouldn't have a TableNumber, as the Player is at multiple tables over time.  Player might have an InitialTableNumber, but that would be a separate relationship.

Comment: That's just a historical way to identify a player. I'm actually not using that model for this application.. Like I said, associating a Round with 3 different Table Objects (This Table, and which initial tables the players involved in it came from) would be even worse)

I just want a proper way to define the relationship of which players belong to a given round without EntityFramework deciding I mean something I didn't intend.